# folder_picker for Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

The web app I'm working on requires the user to select a folder to create a json file in. I've looked online but this is only possible if I hard-code the directory in the code.

Is there any alternative to the folder_picker package for flutter web?

Comment: @AldyYuan Picking an image for reading and picking a folder for writing are fundamentally different things. Your link will not help.

Comment: I need to upload all files in a picked folder. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> The web app I'm working on requires the user to select a folder to create a json file in.

That can never work. A web app, no matter what language is used, cannot write to the users file system directly. If it could, that would be a major security problem, that you would hear about in headline news.

You will need to talk to whoever required that to be a feature. It cannot be done with a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used this feature to select and upload a whole folder into my Flutter web app.
By default it is possible

Comment: This should be a comment on the post and not the answer.